# how i make a script that about automatic press "E" in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am playing a game, name:dynast.io . i try make a script for it, about auto press "E" when i hold"F", but i failed.I very need it even if i don't have i can't play that game, please help me.

```
let intervalId = null;

function sendE() {
    const eKeyEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
        key: 'e',
        code: 'KeyE',
        keyCode: 69,
        which: 69
    });
    document.dispatchEvent(eKeyEvent);
}

function startSendingE() {
    intervalId = setInterval(sendE, 50); // 每隔 50 毫秒发送一次 E 键
}

function stopSendingE() {
    clearInterval(intervalId); // 停止发送 E 键
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.key === 'F') {
        startSendingE();
    }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
    if (event.key === 'F') {
        stopSendingE();
    }
});
```

Comment: please, rewrite your question, it's confusing